# ASIDownLoadCache doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, asihttprequest

```
 ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
request.requestHeaders = header;
request.requestMethod = @"GET";
request.tag = DBRequestTypeChannelCategory;
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
[request setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*3];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

this is my code about http
and if i turn my phone to fly model.
i got this

```
Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x1fd67bf0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1fd66bf0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you've posted means that the crash was from a connection failure, which makes sense if you have airplane mode enabled. You should be able to eliminate this be setting a failure handler.

```
    [request setFailedBlock:void^{
        //
    }];
```

Or

```
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
```

To access cached data without internet access simply add the following to your request.

```
    [request setCachePolicy:ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
```

In order for this to work you need to make sure that cache storage is set to permanent to prevent the caches from being removed when the user exists the app.

```
    [request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
```

Comment: so you mean even it success load data from cache,it will fire a error.

Comment: @icefox I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: i tried the result is null.I want to have access to the data when there is no internet connection.

Comment: @icefox Sorry about that, I'm running out of ideas here. Have you added `[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];` to `viewDidLoad`? I see you've already manually added this to this request, but it might help.

Comment: I maybe found why it's not work.  NSTimeInterval time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?time=%f",AppDBHost,apiName,time]; this is my url , it will change erverytime

Comment: is that the reason? because cache saved by url as id?